# turn one column into a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a question I would like to ask on dataframes.

I have the following info for each row:

```
"[{'id': 'text1'. 'id2': 'text2', 'info': 'information', 'info2': 'text', 'info3': 'text' , 'info4': ['text_a', ' text_b'], ...... 'meta': {'label1':None', 'label2': None}}]"
```

when I import this into pandas I get this:

```
  title
0 [{'id': 'text1'. 'id2': 'text2', 'info': 'information', 'info2': 'text', 'info3': 'text' , 'info4': ['text_a', ' text_b'], ...... 'meta': {'label1':None', 'label2': None}}]
1 [{'id': 'text1'. 'id2': 'text2', 'info': 'information', 'info2': 'text', 'info3': 'text' , 'info4': ['text_a', ' text_b'], ...... 'meta': {'label1':None', 'label2': None}}]
2 [{'id': 'text1'. 'id2': 'text2', 'info': 'information', 'info2': 'text', 'info3': 'text' , 'info4': ['text_a', ' text_b'], ...... 'meta': {'label1':None', 'label2': None}}]
...
n [{'id': 'text1'. 'id2': 'text2', 'info': 'information', 'info2': 'text', 'info3': 'text' , 'info4': ['text_a', ' text_b'], ...... 'meta': {'label1':None', 'label2': None}}]
```

I have tried:

- .unstack()
- split(",")
- .str.extractall()

... but no luck

is there a way to get this data separated?
thanks

Comment: There is a typo after `text1`. May you try to put it to a dataframe again after putting a comma there. Also, I assumed that `......`  are not in the actual list. They shouldn't be there, too

Comment: It looks like each row is actually just text, which means that nothing you do will work until you evaluate it as code. There isn't enough information here to help you formulate a way to do that though.

Comment: @NuriTaş, yes you are right - 'id': 'text1'. should be 'id': 'text1', 
I placed the "....." to show that there is more information (either more info or more lines)